# TYPO3: OpenGraph imagesize with EXT:news

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I am using the tx_news extension, included with an opengraph image.
This image is implemented with **500 x 258 pixel**.

Where or how can I edit this values?

Facebook recommended **1200 x 630 pixel** or a minimum of **600 x 315 pixel**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is set in the Details/Opengraph partial.

```xml
<n:metaTag
        property="og:image"
        content="{f:uri.image(src:'{newsItem.firstPreview.uid}', treatIdAsReference:1, maxWidth:'500')}"
        forceAbsoluteUrl="1" />
```

You can copy the default file from `EXT:news/Resources/Private/Partials/Details/Opengraph.html` to your website extension (or wherever you have you website files) and change it there. If you're using the default extension TypoScript, you can then set the TypoScript constant `plugin.tx_news.view.partialRootPath` to this location. For example, if you copy the file to `EXT:website_mysite/Resources/Private/Partials/Extensions/news/Details/Opengraph.html`, you need to set the constant to `EXT:website_mysite/Resources/Private/Partials/Extensions/news/`.

Comment: Thanks.
I already found this element too. I changed it, but nothing happend. Today I tried again and it worked. Strange.

Comment: I changed it in the news extension itself as well, see https://github.com/georgringer/news/commit/5ce3fbd737af67bb5f98a32ccbffa511ac98d3cc

Thanks for the reminder!